# Pythonic way to partition a list in exactly two groups

Tags: python, iterator

Basically what I want to do is take two lists of objects and based on some test and divide them into two lists depending on whether the result is `True` or `False`.  Sort of what `filter()` does, except that instead of determining if it's in or out it determines which list/iterator to go to.  I've made this attempt using `itertools.groupby()`:

```
import random
from itertools import groupby

class FooObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.key = random.choice((True, False))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Foo: %s>' % self.key

foos = [FooObject() for _ in range(10)]
left, right = [], []

groups = groupby(sorted(foos, key=lambda o: o.key), lambda o: o.key)
for k, group in groups:
    if k:
        right = list(group)
    else:
        left = list(group)

print left
print right
```

This gets the job done, but just wondering if there is a clearner/simpler way. I realize I could use `filter()` (or the equivalent list comprehension) and do it in two passes, but what fun is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only have 2 buckets, you can use a ternary:

```
d={'left':[],'right':[]}
for e in (random.random() for i in xrange(50)):
    d['left' if e<0.5 else 'right'].append(e)
```

With more than 2 buckets, use a function that returns keys already defined or use a default dict with a list:

```
def f(i):
   return int(i*10)

DoL=defaultdict(list)
for e in (random.random() for i in xrange(50)):
   DoL[f(e)].append(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a function that consumes the source only once and returns an dictionary-like object, each member of which is a generator, that yields values from the source as lazily as possible:

```
def partition(it, fun):

    class x(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.buf = {}

        def flush(self, val):
            for p in self.buf.get(val, []):
                yield p
            self.buf.pop(val, None)

        def __getitem__(self, val):
            for p in self.flush(val): yield p
            while True:
                try:
                    p = next(it)
                except StopIteration:
                    break
                v = fun(p)
                if v == val:
                    yield p
                else:
                    self.buf.setdefault(v, []).append(p)
            for p in self.flush(val): yield p

    return x()
```

Example of use:

```
def primes(): # note that this is an endless generator
    yield 2
    p, n = [], 3
    while True:
        if all(n % x for x in p):
            p.append(n)
            yield n
        n += 2


p = partition(primes(), lambda x: x % 3)
# each member of p is endless as well

for x in p[1]:
    print x
    if x > 200: break

for x in p[2]:
    print x
    if x > 200: break
```